# C++ Using namespase std, using std::xxx or just std::x?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I know that there are more possibilities to use the namespaces. By using the syntax `using namespace std;` at the beginning it is loading all the `std` namespace, but I am using just a few (`cout`, `cerr`, `endl`, `vector`, `string`).

How would you suggest me to do:

1. `using namesapace std` - load it all?
2. `using std::cout; using std::endl; using std::cerr; using std::vector; using std::string` - load just what I need?
3. call the namespace before every `cout`, `cerr`, `endl`, `vector`, `string`?

Comment: it all depends. what does your codebase presently do?

Comment: @DanielA.White can you present some king of example, it is not very clear to me?

Comment: what does the app you are working on currently do?

Comment: In fact it is a little more complex, I use also OpenCV and Boost. It reads some images and I am trying to create a classifier based on BagOfWords.

Comment: At the beginning of what? I'd say whichever, but none of them in a header file, ever.

Comment: This is personal. I enforce a coding standard "no using in headers". Personally I rarely use them in sources too. For example, in your case, you *might* be using boost::shared_ptr with pre-C++11. Then you migrate to C++11 and you get std::shared_ptr. Now you have a clash. Stuff in `boost` has a habit of becoming `std`.

Comment: aha, thanks, so never use `using` in headers!! Good to know

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon: Look at my answer again. "never use using in headers" is too broad, as inline functions may appear in headers, and inside inline functions `using` is OK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, avoid `using` at global scope in header files.

Example:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#include <string>

using std::string; // bad

string s();

#endif
```

If you do this, you force the `using` down everyone's throat who includes the header:

```
#include "header.h" // also got `std::string`, which I perhaps didn't want
```

In implementation files or in the body of inline functions in header files, `using` can be used more liberally:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#include <string>

template <class T>
std::string f(T t) // still explicitly qualifying here
{
  using std::string; // OK
  string s = "...";
  // ...
}

#endif
```

However, note that just explicitly qualifying *everything*, i.e. writing `std::string`, `std::cout` etc. everywhere, is a very common accepted style. I personally do this:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#include <string>

template <class T>
std::string f(T t) // explicitly qualifying here
{
  std::string s = "..."; // and here, too
  // ...
}

#endif
```

You'll certainly hear a lot of competent programmers arguing for and against it. The only thing which every competent programmer I know agrees upon is to avoid `using` for the first case I mentioned.

Comment: indeed never have using in headers, the rest is debatable and all correct imo

Answer (score 2):

The answer is at least somewhat opinion-based. The only "rule" I would suggest is to never `using namespace std` (or any other namespace) in a header file, because you then inflict that `using` on everyone who includes you.

In a cpp file, there is more flexibility. Personally, I almost always just skip the `using` and type `std::` when I need it. It's not that long, it makes it obvious what you're trying to do, and it prevents name collisions if you happen to use one of the standard library names for one of your own functions or classes.

Comment: Yes, this is the case of `vector` that is in `cv` and `std` both

Comment: I should add that although I forgot to mention it, I completely agree with [what Christian Hackl said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24307563/3549027) regarding `usings` at block scope.

Answer (score 0):

It is really a matter of preference and the scope of the code.

If you are writing simple short codes only then you should probably go with the first one and not think about it too much. But if you are writing code with many blocks and unlocalized variables, you should consider defining your namespaces.